# How to Search in the database according to Month and Year chosen from Combo Boxes?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have an application where I register some information into the database where I have a Column (DateTime). In this column I insert the date from a DateTimePicker.

Now I want to make a search button which searches according to the date chosen from Comboboxes... but in this Comboboxes I left only one option, to select MONTH and YEAR... how can I make an SELECT query that selects all information according to the Month and Year chosen from the ComboBoxes?

Comment: Check ` datepart` in sqlserver

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from <table>
where month(searchDate)=Month_from_box and Year(searchDate)=Year_from_box
```

However, depending on the size of your data, this might not be the fastest approach.   If you data is in the 100's or even 1000 rows, this approach might be OK...

Another approach would be to build starting and ending dates in C# from your input and then perform a range search

```
select * from <table>
where searchDate between Start_date_from_C# and End_Date_from_C#
```

If you go that approach, be sure to consider the time portion, make it 0 in first date and 23:59:59 in the End Date

If you have an index on the date field, the second approach will be faster...

Comment: Is that properly parameterized?

Comment: with (searchDate) you mean the Column name in my sql database? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, replace <table> with your table name and searchDate with your date field name

Comment: If you use `BETWEEN` just be aware that it does take into account the time, so it will appear *exclusive*. For example, `searchDate BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '1/31/2013'` would only include data with the searchDate from '1/1/2013' to *exactly* '1/31/2013 00:00:00.000'.

Comment: That's why I mentioned to make the time portion 0 for the start date and 23:59:59 for the end date...

Comment: @Sparky - Understood... just clarifying for the OP's sake. I +1'd your answer....

Comment: @Sparky - Also, depending on the datetime format, '23:59:59' may not be enough - you'd need '23:59:59.997'

Comment: @Sparky: Everything between 23:59:59,001 and the next day is ignored. Very unlikely, I know. But possible, and therefore not correct. Nicarus: Thanks for the update.

Comment: Good point, shouldn't have assumed that one second precision might be enough...   Thanks for the adjustments

Answer (score 1):

All solutions which use either the `datepart` or `month` and `year` functions make it impossible for the server to optimize the query by using an index.

The only valid solution in terms of performance is @Sparkys second approach using the `between` clause. He also described the problems arising with the time fraction. That is why I would prefer using a plain `date` column (instead of `datetime`). Then you can write

```
select * 
from YourTable 
where DateColumn between <FirstDayOfSelectedMonthAndYear> 
                     and <LastDayOfSelectedMonthAndYear>
```

because when using a datetime column and the range of

```
between '20121201' and '20121231 23:59:59'
```

Everything after the last second of the year and midnight still gets discarded. Although it is very unlikely it is technically not correct.

@Nicarus suggests widening the ending time to 23:59:59,997'. This seems to work but is 'ugly' (but, wtf, it works!)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you store the combo values into Integer variables in your C# before putting them in the SQL query. As others have alluded, SQL Injection attacks are possible if you allow the direct user input to be placed inside a SQL String.

Assuming you have 2 int variables "intMonth", "intYear", and the field name of "dateFieldname", the following SQL should work.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [table]
WHERE   datepart[mm,dateFieldname] = intMonth
    AND datepart[yyy,dateFieldname] = intYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

`Select * from tablename where
datepart(mm,datecolumnname)=@cmboxMonthvalue nd datepart(yyyy,datecolumnname)=@ComboboxYearvalue`

Comment: Are your combo box values  properly parameterized?

Comment: @robert harvey  - I agree to perevent frm sql injection must use parameterised query.